# Query for property CurrentEdition of Visio Application Object

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly, visio

The visio application object can be controlled in c# programs via the assembly Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio. The documentation of the visio application object 2010 is showing the property **CurrentEdition**:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio-help/HV080350129.aspx

However in my small c# application the property does not exist - although a reference to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio has been created. Now my question is how this property can be made accessible for an external application? In case the Interop assemblies are restricted do you know another assembly to get this done? Thanks!

```
using System;

namespace VisioTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.Application visioApp;

            visioApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.Application();

            if (visioApp.Application.CurrentEdition == Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.VisEdition.visEditionStandard)
            {
                // standard edition etc.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried this exact code and it compiles and returns a value for CurrentEdition.

Comment: Interesting. For me Visual Studio 2010 underlines CurrentEdition and VisEdition in red as unknown. Can you see which version of the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio assembly you are referencing to (for me it is 12.0.0.0)? Do you use a higher version of Visual Studio?

Comment: I have Office 2010 and Visio in x86/x64 installed. Since it runs on a x64 OS the x64 editions should have been installed. Still my program will not compile in x86 or x64 or mixed.

Comment: Are you saying you've got both 32 and 64 bit versions of Visio installed on your machine?

Comment: @John: first I was not sure because I have used the ISO that offers both editions (x86 and x64). But the task manager marks visio.exe clearly as *32. The same is true for winword.exe, excel.exe and so forth. Another important information might be that I am using .NET 2.0.

Comment: @Frankenstein - I am referencing v14 of the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio. v14 is for Visio 2010. v12 is for Visio 2007.

Comment: @saveenr: good point! Although I have installed Office and Visio with standard settings (Interop is part of the default installation) the v14 was not installed. However, after installing the Office PIA 2010 package I can reference v14 too. I am a bit puzzled about that because I will have to rely on the fact that the interop libraries are available on client machines per default installation. Thank you very much for your help!